# Suggest site-specific "jobs near you" listings

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On the main [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) site there is a "jobs near you" widget which displays a couple of job summaries. It acts as an advertisement leading people to [careers.stackoverfow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). The highlighted jobs are *generic technical jobs* in the viewer's region.

[image]

A suggestion is to allow Stack Exchange sites to personalise this widget so that more relevant jobs can be shown on each site.

For example, on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) it would display "GIS jobs near you". On [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) it would display "Design jobs near you".

There are lots of sites within the Stack Exchange network where this would make sense. Each site's admins could choose whether they enable the functionality on their site.

Comment: It's my understanding that the intention is the jobs only be advertised on Stack Overflow—after all, the site is called Stack __Overflow__ Careers, not Stack __Exchange__ Careers. That being said, this is an interesting idea, and I'd like to see an official response.

Comment: Personally, I spend a few hours each day on GIS.stackexchange.com - I very rarely go to the mothership. If the goal of the widget is to drive traffic to the Careers site, it would seem logical to bring it to the people....

Comment: GIS is a bit of an old boys club anyway, you're either in or you're not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we're focusing on programming and sysadmin jobs. This means that we serve job listings on Stack Overflow and Server Fault only.

While this may be something that we look at in the future, it's pretty low on the priority list. Software Developers (and to a lesser degree sysadmins) are our core user base, and we're focused on them first and foremost.

However, we definitely *are* looking at implementing some more customization features for those job listings in the relative near future, but nothing is set in stone at the moment.

Comment: I don't have the numbers but a significant subset (ca 10-20%) of GIS SE users are programmers/developers or system administrators.

Comment: @PolyGeo yeah that's a good point. Many (most?) people who use a Stack Exchange site are probably techy. Putting the Jobs Near You widget on other sites could lead to an increased exposure for the core user base too.

Comment: From http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/819/introducing-jobs-in-your-sidebar it looks like GIS SE *was* being looked as a test site for Careers ideas a couple of years ago.